# Creating a SQL Loop to Change the Table Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am needing to change the ending number of the table name in a loop to go from 1 through 12. This is a more straight forward example of my actual problem, but if this can be solved, then I can duplicate the results later on (Actual problem is using the past 12 months on a rolling basis for a report and all of the individual months are stored by themselves). I know I can create a string query with each query being unioned to the other, but I still have to edit all 12 queries when a change is needed. I am looking for a more efficient process.

```
Declare @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @i INT
CREATE TABLE #Accounts (Account varchar(10))
SET @i = 1


WHILE @i <= 12
BEGIN
Select @Query = 'Select COUNT(ACCT) From dbo.table_'+quotename(@i)
   INSERT INTO #Accounts
    EXEC(@Query)
   SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

SELECT Account FROM #Accounts
```

When I run this code, I get invalid object names for the table because it doesn't attached the number to the end of the name. Will this be possible using a while loop or will I have to start looking into cursors?

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT` it. If you did that, you'd see that `table[1]` is not a valid object name. This type of SQL, however, strongly suggests you have design flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your QUOTENAME should be around the entire table name.

```
Declare @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @i INT
CREATE TABLE #Accounts (Account varchar(10))
SET @i = 1


WHILE @i <= 12
BEGIN

print quotename(@i)
Select @Query = 'Select COUNT(ACCT) From dbo.'+quotename('table_'+convert(nvarchar,@i))
   INSERT INTO #Accounts
   EXEC(@Query)
   SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

SELECT Account FROM #Accounts
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. I will mark it as accepted once it allows me to.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do `UNION ALL`, you just need to construct the dynamic query all at once, with no loops.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
'INSERT INTO #Accounts (Account)
' +
(
SELECT STRING_AGG(
    N'Select COUNT(ACCT) From dbo.' + QUOTENAME(N'table_' + i),
    CAST(N'
UNION ALL
' AS nvarchar(max)))
FROM (VALUES('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('10'),('11'),('12') ) AS v(i)
);

EXEC (@sql);
```

**I question, though, why the column in the temp table is `varchar` if you are inserting a `COUNT`**

Comment: Some of the characteristics were not changed when I created this general example. I have to loop through month/year combinations 12.2019 through 12.2020, so the first answer works best.

Comment: If you supply exactly what you need, I'm sure that could be done without a loop also. Sounds like a tally table join